# what's property copy means in Cocoa's Framework?(like UITabBar's items property)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, copy

In UITabBar.h, a propery signed copy

@property(nonatomic,copy)   NSArray             *items;        // get/set visible

It's a array
And what "copy" means?
copy NSArray container obj?
copy every obj NSArray contains?
or something.

### so there's a test

```
UITabBar* testBar = [[UITabBar alloc] init];
UITabBarItem* item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
NSArray* array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:item, nil];

NSLog(@"bar:%p,%d", testBar, testBar.retainCount);
NSLog(@"item:%p,%d", item, item.retainCount);
NSLog(@"array:%p,%d", array, array.retainCount);

testBar.items = array;

NSLog(@"that item:%p,%d", [testBar.items lastObject], [[testBar.items lastObject] retainCount]);
NSLog(@"testBar.items:%p,%d", testBar.items, testBar.items.retainCount);
```

### result

bar:0x96a9750,1

item:0x96aa230,2

array:0x96aa280,1

that item:0x96aa230,2

testBar.items:0x96aa280,6

why neither container array nor obj in array has been "copied"?

Comment: retainCount is useless. Don't call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the copy has not been made in this case is that `NSArray` is *immutable*. You do not need to make a copy of it to guard against changes to the array, because such changes cannot be made; it is sufficient to retain the same immutable array.

If you try this experiment with `NSMutableArray`, you will get a different result.

Comment: bar:0x96b5ae0,1
item:0x96b6560,2
mutable array:0x96b65b0,1
that item:0x96b6560,3
testBar.items:0x96b6610,5  yeah I think you told the point, the container array has been copied,thanks

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- collection `-copy` is always shallow. It doesn't copy the collections elements (In fact, nothing guarantees that these elements are even copyable – i.e. are conforming to `NSCopying` protocol). This explains why `obj` is not copied – it doesn't get any extra retain.
- Foundation tries to optimizes its implementation of `-copy` to `-retain` whenever is possible. For example, `-[NSString copy]` is a retain for immutable strings. Since collection copies are shallow, the same optimization works for immutable collections. That's why `array` is not copied but just retained.

Comment: just a test shows that sometimes copy a immutable string even not retain,maybe os shared a certain string for only one copy in memory, thanks

Comment: Clarification: Arrays won't *always* be copied; only immutable ones may. If you try to set `items` to a mutable array, you'll find it set to a copy.